# How to dynamically switch orientation of TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

The general orientation is set as:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
 />
```

I need to switch the `TextView` orientation back and forth for different views so it better handles the available space.

Comment: Do you mean when you rotate the device ? Else it would be android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: `android:orientation` attribute is for `LinearLayout` not `TextView`

Comment: No. I need to switch the view orientation for different inputs back and forth on the same page so better handle the available space.
Thx

Comment: Okay. How to change the orientation of a <textView from what is stated in the <LinearLayout ?

Comment: Maybe create different views and load and hide them accordingly.

Comment: Removed unnecessary information. Fixed the title. The question can be improved by providing more details about the problem such as why you want to apply this solution. So instead of mentioning a random "how to", you should ask why you want to do this. So someone can suggest better approach to the original problem.